# Loop within Loop causing undesired output

Tags: php

I have the following loop...

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo '<span class="srch-val-'.$i.'">'.apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
}
```

within...

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
  echo "<div class='clearfix card-prod ".($i==0?'first':'')."'><span class='card-title'>";
  echo the_title();
  echo "</span>";

  foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
    $keyt = trim($key);
    if ( '_' == $keyt{0} || 'pricing' == $keyt || 'vehicleType' == $keyt || 'coverageRegion' == $keyt || 'locationType' == $keyt )
      continue;
    $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
    $value = implode($values,', ');
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                echo '<span class="srch-val-'.$i.'">'.apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
            }

  }
   echo "\n"; echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/top-choice.jpg" alt="Top Choice" class="topchoice">';echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/cards/dummy.png" />';      echo the_excerpt()."</div>";}
  $i++;
```

endwhile;

When I execute my code however, say my while() loop returns 4 values, my for() loop then outputs 10 of the same thing, in my browser its shown as...

[image]

All I want to do is for each `<span class="srch-val'>` is to add a number after each 'srch-val' class, so srch-val-1, srch-val-2 etc...

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you want? It's obvious that the for loop prints 10 times the same thing because $value doesn't change.

Comment: Do you mean <span class="srch-val-1 srch-val-2 srch-val-3...">Free setup</span>?

Comment: Sorry everyone, 

I have 4 values that are returned without the loop, I want them to be output as such...
<span class="srch-val-1">1500 Sites</span>
<span class="srch-val-2">Fixed Commercial Printing</span>
<span class="srch-val-3">Free Setup</span>
<span class="srch-val-4">Deisel, Ad, Lube</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra for-loop inside your foreach-loop. Remove this loop and just do the echo directly inside the foreach-loop and increment `$i` each time you actually use it.

Like this:

```
$i = 1;
while ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    $query->the_post();
    if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() )
    {
        echo "<div class='clearfix card-prod ".($i==0?'first':'')."'><span class='card-title'>";
        echo the_title();
        echo "</span>";

        foreach ( (array) $keys as $key )
        {
            $keyt = trim($key);
            if ( '_' == $keyt{0} || 'pricing' == $keyt || 'vehicleType' == $keyt || 'coverageRegion' == $keyt || 'locationType' == $keyt )
                continue;
            $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
            $value = implode($values,', ');

            echo '<span class="srch-val-'.$i.'">'.apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
            $i++;    // move the incrementer here so that you only increment when you actually use it.
        }

        echo "\n"; echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/top-choice.jpg" alt="Top Choice" class="topchoice">';echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/cards/dummy.png" />';      echo the_excerpt()."</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a variable at the beginning of your foreach-loop (say `$counter == 1;`)

Than your For-loop should be:

```
for($i = $counter; $i <= $counter+10; $i++){
    //do your span-class thing here
}
```

And at the end of the foreach loop do: `$counter += 10;`